# How to reference an application entry point for r.js bundle?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, durandal

When we use non-optimized scripts we can reference an entry point to our application just using an attribute data-main in the following way:

```
<script src="js/require.js" data-main="app/main"></script>
```

The question is how to reference a bundle created using r.js. I've tried the same pattern:

```
<script src="js/require.js" data-main="app/main-built.js"></script>
```

But it doesn't work, unless I do a 'hard' require:

```
<script>
    require(['main'], function () {

    });
</script>
```

Can I avoid this?
And what are the best practice to reference r.js bundle?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you not including `main.js` into your `main-build.js`?

Comment: Saying "it doesn't work" is too vague. You get a timeout, an error on the console, something else? (Add the answer to your question.) Also please add your build configuration and run time configuration to your question and any `<script>` tags (besides the one you've already shown) that you use to start your application.